# DropDownListFor not Triggering OnChange Event

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-chosen

When user clicks on Edit option in webgrid of home.cshtml, "EditService" method is called in home controller which returns the "CreateService" view along with its view model. Everything works fine. but problem is DropDownListFor is not triggering onchange event although value is changed to specified. I need to trigger this event automatically when this view is called.

**View Snippet**

```
@{
List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
{
    Text = "One Shot",
    Value = "1"
});
listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
{
    Text = "Subscription",
    Value = "2"
});
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ServiceType, listItems, new { @class = "chosen-select",  @style =  "width:120px" , @id="cmbServiceType"})


<script>
$(document).on('change', '#cmbServiceType', function () {

    alert($("#cmbServiceType option:selected").val());

    if ($("#cmbServiceType option:selected").val() == "2") {

        //sms mode is selected

        $('#lblequipId').show();
        $('#txtequipId').show();

    }
    else {
        //dial mode is selected

        $('#lblequipId').hide();
        $('#txtequipId').hide();
    }
});

</script>
```

**Controller Snippet**

```
    public ActionResult EditService(int Id)
    {
        WCMSDataContext wcmsContext = new WCMSDataContext();
        ServiceVM serviceVM = new ServiceVM();
        serviceVM.Mode = new Mode();
        serviceVM.Mechanism = new Mechanism();

        var xService = from p in wcmsContext.Services where p.Id == Id select p;

        if (xService.Count() > 0)
        {
            XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNodeList xmlnode;
            // if xml coming via string
            string myXml = xService.First().XML;
            xdoc.LoadXml(myXml);
            //XmlNodeList address = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("Service");
            xmlnode = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("Service");

            xmlnode[0].ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim(); //get all child nodes

            for (int j = 0; j < xmlnode[0].ChildNodes.Count; j++)
            {
                string nodeTitle = xmlnode[0].ChildNodes.Item(j).Name.Trim();
                string nodeValuestr = xmlnode[0].ChildNodes.Item(j).InnerText.Trim();

                if (nodeTitle == "TITLE")
                {
                    serviceVM.Title = nodeValuestr;
                }
                else if (nodeTitle == "LONGDESC")
                {
                    serviceVM.Content = nodeValuestr;
                }
                else if (nodeTitle == "DETAIL")
                {
                    serviceVM.Detail = nodeValuestr;
                }
                else if (nodeTitle == "EQUIPID")
                {
                    serviceVM.EquipId = nodeValuestr;

                    if (nodeValuestr == "0")
                    {
                        serviceVM.ServiceType = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        serviceVM.ServiceType = 2;
                    }
                }
                else if (nodeTitle == "MODE")
                {
                    if (nodeValuestr == "Dial")
                        serviceVM.Mode.ModeType = 1;
                    else
                        serviceVM.Mode.ModeType = 2;
                }
                else if (nodeTitle == "SMSCOMMAND")
                {
                    serviceVM.Mode.SMSCommand = nodeValuestr;
                }
                else if (nodeTitle == "DEACTIVATIONCOMMAND")
                {
                    serviceVM.Mode.DeactivationCommand = nodeValuestr;
                }
                else if (nodeTitle == "DIALCOMMAND")
                {
                    serviceVM.Mode.DialCommand = nodeValuestr;
                }
                else if (nodeTitle == "Mechanism")
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < xmlnode[0].ChildNodes[j].ChildNodes.Count; k++)
                    {
                        nodeTitle = xmlnode[0].ChildNodes[j].ChildNodes.Item(k).Name.Trim();
                        nodeValuestr = xmlnode[0].ChildNodes[j].ChildNodes.Item(k).InnerText.Trim();

                        if (nodeTitle == "Title")
                        {
                            serviceVM.Mechanism.Title = nodeValuestr;
                        }
                        else if (nodeTitle == "Description")
                        {
                            serviceVM.Mechanism.Description = nodeValuestr;
                        }
                        else if (nodeTitle == "Trigger")
                        {
                            serviceVM.Mechanism.Triger = nodeValuestr;
                        }
                        else if (nodeTitle == "Controls")
                        {
                            nodeValuestr = xmlnode[0].ChildNodes[j].ChildNodes.Item(k).InnerText.Trim();
                            string[] s = nodeValuestr.Split(',');
                            int i = 0;
                            serviceVM.Mechanism.Controls = new int[s.Length];
                            foreach (var item in s)
                            {
                                string name = string.Empty;
                                string value = string.Empty;

                                if (item == "1")
                                {
                                    name = "Contact Selector";
                                    value = "1";
                                }
                                else if (item == "2")
                                {
                                    name = "Value Selector";
                                    value = "2";
                                }
                                else if (item == "3")
                                {
                                    name = "Text Box";
                                    value = "3";
                                }

                                serviceVM.Mechanism.Controls[i] = Convert.ToInt32(value);

                                i++;

                                ////Create the select list item you want to add
                                //SelectListItem selListItem = new SelectListItem() {Text = name, Value = value };

                                ////Create a list of select list items - this will be returned as your select list
                                //serviceVM.Mechanism.Controls = new List<SelectListItem>();

                                ////Add select list item to list of selectlistitems
                                //serviceVM.Mechanism.Controls.Add(selListItem);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return View("CreateService", serviceVM);
    }
```

**Home.cshtml**

```
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model);

        @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webgrid-table",           
            headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
            footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
            alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
            selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
            rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
            mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
            columns: new [] {              
                grid.Column("Id", "Id", canSort: true, style: "id"),
                grid.Column("Title", "Title", canSort: true, style: "title"),
                grid.Column(format: item =>                             
                         Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditService","Home", new {Id = item.Id}, null))
                })
```

Comment: You shouldn't use the same `id` for multiple objects.

Comment: Do you mean you want to run the `if (...) {...} else {...};` code when the page loads?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes exactly. and its not working

Comment: @DavidG yes there was id issue i have changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.trigger()` method to trigger an event

```
<script>
  $(document).on('change', '#cmbServiceType', function () {
    if ($("#cmbServiceType option:selected").val() == "2") {
      ....
    } else {
      ....
    }
  });

  $('#cmbServiceType').trigger('change'); // add this

</script>
```